# Getting field from getGetFeatureInfo in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I'm making a `getGetFeatureInfoRequest()` as following:

```
this.map.on('singleclick',(evt) => {
  var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (this.map.getView().getResolution());
  var url = this.layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:25830',
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
  console.log(url);
  if(url){
    var parser = new GeoJSON();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
    }).then(function(response) {
      var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
      console.log("RESP:"+result);
    });
  }

});
```

When the request is made, I receive an html response, which has a `<table>` and a column with the desired value I need to get.

[image: HTML response]

Is there any way to force the server to return data in JSON?

If not, how can I get that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first know if the server is configured to support json as InfoFormat. Check that by reading GetCapabilities, for example

https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities

Find the supported formats for GetFeatureInfo from the response

```
<GetFeatureInfo>
<Format>text/plain</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
<Format>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</Format>
<Format>text/html</Format>
<Format>application/json</Format>
…
```

Format `application/json` looks promising so edit your code and use that as InfoFormat

```
{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
```

All WMS servers do not support json as InfoFormat at all and some servers that have the support are using some other format name than application/json. If you wish to build an application that works with any WMS it will be complicated: read capabilities, find out if it supports json and with what name, if it does not support json use some other supported info format and handle that with your code.